# C# Selenium looping through XPath results

Tags: c#, loops, selenium, xpath

How can i loop through each result from same Xpath?
My code:

```
IList<IWebElement> base = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div[4]/div/table/tbody//td[contains(@style,'text-align: center;')and contains(text(),'?')]/following-sibling::td[1]"));

String[] baseALL = new string[base.Count];
int i = 0;

foreach (IWebElement elm in base)
{
    string uhm = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div[4]/div/table/tbody//td[contains(@style,'text-align: center;')and contains(text(),'?')]/following-sibling::td[1]")).Text;
    string liczba = uhm;
    Console.WriteLine(liczba);
    double d = Convert.ToDouble(liczba.Replace(".", ","));
    if (d < 10)
    {
        foreach (IWebElement wyslij in base)
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div[4]/div/table/tbody//td[contains(@style,'text-align: center;')and contains(text(),'?')]/following-sibling::td[2]/a")).Click();
        }
    }   
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td//table//td//a[@class='manager_icon'] [@title='Asystent Farmera']")).Click();
}
```

My xpath gives results like

```
<td>1.8</td>
<td>3.2</td>
<td>4.8</td>
<td>7.8</td>
```

I want to loop through each one and compare (if its less than 10 Click there)
But it always picks first result, how can i jump to next one? Same for Click Loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative xpath instead of absolute xpath.

Find element always return first element. You have to have change the xpath by including nth .

Try this and if doesn't work add your html to the question.

```
int i = 0;

foreach (IWebElement elm in base)
{
    i++;
    string uhm = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div[4]/div/table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td[contains(@style,'text-align: center;')and contains(text(),'?')]/following-sibling::td[1]")).Text;
    string liczba = uhm;
    Console.WriteLine(liczba);
}
```